# Field in contact form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm new to PHP and have a problem with the following contact form: 
The variable:  $empresa  = $_POST['empresa']; is not working... and I don't understand where the problem is. When I try to use it in the E-Mail sent, it just doesn't show up.

```
$received_subject = 'Has sido contactado desde www.company.com por ' . $name . '. Empresa' . $empresa . '.' ;
```

**This is the PHP I'm using: ** 
THANKS in advance

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$empresa  = $_POST['empresa'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Has olvidado escribir tu mensaje.</div>';
    exit();
} 



if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Tienes que poner un nombre.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Por favor pon tu dirección de e-mail, para poder ponernos en contacto contigo.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Dirección de e-mail inválida, inténtelo nuevamente.</div>';
    exit();
}

$address = "mail@mail.com";


$received_subject = 'Has sido contactado desde www.company.com por ' . $name . '. Empresa' . $empresa . '.' ;

$received_body = "$name te ha contactado desde www.company.com " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$received_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$received_reply = "Responder a $name $email o llamar al teléfono: $phone | Empresa: $empresa ";

$message = wordwrap( $received_body . $received_content . $received_reply, 100 );

$header = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$header .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $received_subject, $message, $header)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<h2>E-Mail enviado con éxito</h2>";
    echo "<p>Gracias <strong>$name</strong>, tu mensaje ha sido enviado.</p>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

MY form is here:

```
                            <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

                                <fieldset id="contact_form">
                                    <label for="name">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="empresa">
                                        <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="email">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="phone">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Número de teléfono">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="comments">
                                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Mensaje *"></textarea>
                                    </label>
                                    <p class="obligatorio"> * = Obligatorio</p>

                                    <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-default btn-black" id="submit" value="Enviar">
                                </fieldset>

                            </form>
```

Comment: where is your `form`?

Comment: I've added my form below the code

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't know how to apply your question into the code

Comment: add the command after the `if(!$_POST) exit;` line (don't forget ; at end)

Comment: I'm getting the following even though I put something into the empresa field: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "andreas" ["empresa"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(21) "someemail@mail.com" ["phone"]=> string(6) "ölcsa" ["comments"]=> string(16) "öacmslöcmaösc" }

Comment: Are you sure your host supports sending emails?

Comment: Yes, e-mails are being sent and received without problems. I just need to add this "Company" field and I don't know why it isn't showing up. That's all. Thanks

Comment: are you using special characters in this field? Something that may interfere with surrounding quotes?

Comment: No, i don't think so. I just have the code you can find below. And I copied other fields that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your other post variables are working then it sounds like the $_POST['empresa'] variable is not making it to the php page.  To debug your script you can either switch your form method to GET to see the query string in the browser url or use a tool like firebug which is a add on for firefox. You will get error on your php page when you switch to the GET method on your html form. Don't worry about that your are just trying to see if the empressa variable is being sent via the http Post request.

Ok your variable dump should show this based on the code your provided

```
array
  'name' => string 'Larry' (length=5)
  'empresa' => string 'Lane' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'ok@yahoo.com' (length=12)
  'phone' => string '123' (length=3)
  'comments' => string 'ok' (length=2)
```

So empresa is making it to the page just fine. I did notice that you do not have an opening form tag for your form? You should have something like this with the names of your file in place of the ones I used for testing of course.

```
<form name="testform" action="testingpostvariables.php" method="POST">
```

Place echo $message; after your line of code in your php file

```
    $message = wordwrap( $received_body . $received_content . $received_reply, 100 );

    $echo message;
```

When I did it empresa showed up.

Ok put this code in seperate php file and test it so we can figure out why "empresa" is not showing up. I would also trying refreshing your browser before testing this file to make sure there is no bad cached results.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

                                <fieldset id="contact_form">
                                    <label for="name">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="empresa">
                                        <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="email">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail *">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="phone">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Número de teléfono">
                                    </label>

                                    <label for="comments">
                                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Mensaje *"></textarea>
                                    </label>
                                    <p class="obligatorio"> * = Obligatorio</p>

                                    <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-default btn-black" id="submit" value="Enviar">
                                </fieldset>

                            </form>



<?php




//debug
echo var_dump($_POST);

//debug
if(!$_POST){

    echo "NO POST";

    //exit;
}
else{

    echo "POSTED";
}

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$empresa  = $_POST['empresa'];

//impress is posting just fine

$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Has olvidado escribir tu mensaje.</div>';
    exit();
} 



if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Tienes que poner un nombre.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Por favor pon tu dirección de e-mail, para poder ponernos en contacto contigo.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Dirección de e-mail inválida, inténtelo nuevamente.</div>';
    exit();
}

$address = "mail@mail.com";


$received_subject = 'Has sido contactado desde www.company.com por ' . $name . '. Empresa' . $empresa . '.' ;

//debug
//$empressa is still working fine


$received_body = "$name te ha contactado desde www.company.com " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$received_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$received_reply = "Responder a $name $email o llamar al teléfono: $phone | Empresa: $empresa ";



$message = wordwrap( $received_body . $received_content . $received_reply, 100 );

echo $message;

$header = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$header .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;

/*
if(mail($address, $received_subject, $message, $header)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<h2>E-Mail enviado con éxito</h2>";
    echo "<p>Gracias <strong>$name</strong>, tu mensaje ha sido enviado.</p>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
 */
```

This what my result looked like with the empresa value at the end(Lane is the empresa value I entered in the form).

POSTEDLarry te ha contactado desde www.company.com "This is a really long message ok lets see whats going on with this php code it is not sending the empresa variable" Responder a Larry mail@mail.com o llamar al telÃ©fono: 12345678 | Empresa: Lane

Comment: I've added the GET method, but didn't get any errors, i also didn't receive an e-mail with that info.

Comment: I'm getting the following even though I put something into the empresa field: 
 array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "andreas" ["empresa"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(21) "someemail@mail.com" ["phone"]=> string(6) "ölcsa" ["comments"]=> string(16) "öacmslöcmaösc" }

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, BUT echo $message; Displays all information in the message, but "empresa" is still not showing up.

Comment: Hi Larry, I've added it, but stil no luck... I get nothing from the empresa field.

Comment: I get "empresa"]=> string(0) even though I put something into the field.

Comment: I am trying to debug the client side code on your website and I am getting the same results as you even though it works fine on my local web server.  Have you tried removing the word wrap function call from your php $message variable maybe your server is doing something weird. Wouldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Can you tell me which javascript file displays the results in your #results div

Comment: I found it, I going to check it out to see if there is anything weird going on.

Comment: I suppose is js/custom.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok in your "custom.js" file you have the following line of code that could be causing some problems.

```
  $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                empresa: $('#empresa').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                phone: $('#phone').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(), //remove this comma
```

There should not be a comma after the last property value try removing that to see if you get the value of empresa from the jquery code. Try it and let me know i

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, by changing the word empresa with something else. 
I think there was some sort of collision using this word.

Thanks so much for your help!